# How to adjust positioning of text on top of arrows in sequencediagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgf-umlsd

How to adjust positioning of text on top of arrows in sequencediagram. For example, the following code produces output in which "Text1 Text1" and "Text2 Text2 Text2" are positioned at top of center of the arrow. How to position the text at top of left or right of the arrow?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lingmacros}
\usepackage{tree-dvips}
\usepackage{pgf-umlsd}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart,shapes,shadows,arrows.meta,arrows,decorations.markings,trees,positioning,decorations.markings,calc,fit,chains,intersections,decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}


\begin{sequencediagram}
    \newinst {a}  {AAA}
    \newinst {b}  {BBB}
    \newinst {c}  {CCC}
    \newinst {d}  {DDD}
    \newinst {e}  {EEE}
    \newinst {f}  {FFF}
    \newinst {g}  {GGG}

    \postlevel

    \begin{messcall}{a} {\shortstack[l]{\\
            $Text1\ Text1$\\
            $Text2\ Text2\ Text2$\\
            $$}} {g}
    \end{messcall}

\end{sequencediagram}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not directly possible to do that without somehow modifying `pgf-umlsd` I think, because the node in question is added by the following:

```
\draw[->,>=angle 60] ({cf\thecallevel}) -- (ct\thecallevel)
  node[midway, above] {#3};
```

As you can see, the node in question doesn't have any styles you can modify, and no argument of the environment is passed to its options. But it is possible to do such modifications "on the fly" in a document, by patching the macro `\messcall`.

First, define a new style:

```
\tikzset{messcall/.style={above,midway}}
```

Then load the `xpatch` package:

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
```

Now patch `\messcall`, the macro that is called when the `messcall` environment is started and where that node is drawn, to replace `node[midway,above]` with `node[messcall]`:

```
\xpatchcmd{\messcall}{node[midway, above]}{node[messcall]}{}{}
```

Now you can modify the position of the node along the line like this:

```
\tikzset{messcall/.append style={very near start}}
\begin{messcall}%...
```

There are various other options in addition to `very near start`, described in section 17.8 *Placing Nodes on a Line or Curve Explicitly* of the TikZ manual, including `very near end`, `near start`/`near end`, and the generic `pos=<fraction>`, where `<fraction>` is a value between 0 and 1.

Unrelated note: if `Text 1` and `Text 2` is actual text, and not math, don't use math mode. If you want italic text use `\textit{...}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgf-umlsd}
\tikzset{messcall/.style={above,midway}}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\messcall}{node[midway, above]}{node[messcall]}{}{}
\begin{document}
\begin{sequencediagram}
    \newinst {a}  {AAA}
    \newinst {b}  {BBB}
    \newinst {c}  {CCC}
    \newinst {d}  {DDD}
    \newinst {e}  {EEE}
    \newinst {f}  {FFF}
    \newinst {g}  {GGG}

    \postlevel

    \tikzset{messcall/.append style={very near start}}
    \begin{messcall}{a} {\shortstack[l]{\\
            Text1  Text1\\
            Text2 Text2 Text2
            }} {g}

    \end{messcall}

\end{sequencediagram}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The start (from) and the end (to) of the arrow are labeled by `(cf\thecallevel)` and `(ct\thecallevel)`, but `\thecallevel` may change, so this nodes are not available outside the environment like this. So you can use something like :

```
\begin{messcall}{a}{Middle}{g}
    \node[above right] at (cf\thecallevel) {Start};
    \node[above left] at (ct\thecallevel) {End};
\end{messcall}
```

**Note:** You can access them later by `(cf1)` and `(ct1)` if the value of `\thecallevel` was `1` at the moment of the arrow draw.